# How to get web elements that have not a specific text

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium and Java to write a test, I have some confusion with xpath, for example:

shouldn't  `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.
xpath("//span[not(text()='a')]")));` or `//span[text()!='a']` bring me all spans whose text is not 'a' ?

Comment: Can you share the html?

Answer (score 0):

There is a big difference in using the `!=` operator over using `not()`.
The first one checks the inequality between the `$node-set` and `$value` only when the `$node-set` is not empty.

Let's take for example the following HTML excerpt:

```
...
<div>
    <span>a</span>
</div>
...
```

In this case, `//span[text()!='b']` will return `true` just like `//span[not(text()='b')]`.
However, if, for some reason you want to apply the same logic for the `div` tag, `//div[text()!='b']` will return `false` because there isn't even a single node for which the inequality holds, while `//div[not(text()='b')]` will return `true`.

As a bottom line (and personal recommendation) you should not use the `!=` operator for checking node-sets and go with `not()` instead.